# kubectl cp will not write to pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I'm moving from Kubernetes v1.17.4 to v1.18.3

The command `kubectl -n nameSpace cp file pod-xxxx-yyyy:file` will not write to the pod.

There are no error messages generated

Copying from a pod works just fine.

YAML for creating the pod

```
apiVersion: apps/v2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: acadmin
  namespace: iiabe3h
  labels:
    app: acadmin
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: acadmin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: acadmin
    spec:
      schedulerName: stork
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1800
      securityContext:
        supplementalGroups: [12312, 65432, 3399, 1000001]
        fsGroup: 1000
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: "true"
      volumes:
      - name: acadmin-logs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: acadmin-logs
      - name: acadmin-config
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: acadmin-config
      containers:
      - name: acadmin
        image: acadmin:latest
        env:
        - name: spring.profiles.active
          value: "e3h"
        - name: AccessControlFilter.props
          value: "/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/AccessControlFilter.props"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: acadmin-logs
          mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log
        - name: acadmin-config
          mountPath: /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration
```

Comment: what's your pod definition? Can you post it? Thanks

Comment: Yes, because your pod is apparently running with a non-root UID; I bet you can `kubectl cp file pod-xxxx-yyyy:/tmp/file` and it'll work fine; the thing you are experiencing is _by design_

Comment: thank  you - i did try to write to /tmp - there was no effect

NOTE: This same yaml is one that was used with v1.17.4 of kubernets and it worked, but now with v1.18.3 it does not

Comment: Is your yaml file correct? your ApiVersion seems to be incorrect. Can you validate it?